# Load UIButton After UIView Loads

Tags: ios, user-interface, uibutton

I have a set of buttons displayed in the center of a UIViewController.  To give the effect that the buttons are popping/appearing on the view one after the other when the view loads I am trying to figure out to load UIButtons after my UIViewController loads or alternatively load within a second of each other so that they load quickly but that there is a visual animated pop of the button after the view loads.

Does anyone have an example of doing this with UIButton?

Comment: What you are looking for is probably the "viewWillAppear" method on UIViewController

Comment: You can always increment the alpha. start at 0.0f and end at 1.0f. It will give the fading in effect, and will start out invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, when the view controller receives a call to `viewDidLoad` you want to setup your buttons so they have a zero `alpha`.

Then, in `viewDidAppear:` you can configure a set of animations to show the buttons using:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>
                      delay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>
                    options:<#(UIViewAnimationOptions)#>
                 animations:<#^(void)animations#>
                 completion:<#^(BOOL finished)completion#>]
```

Using the `delay` to space out the display of each button and the `animations` block to specify how the buttons appear. In the animation block you can set the `alpha` to 1 to make the buttons appear. You could also add a scale `transform` to the button so it changes in size (for the pop effect).

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillA pear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    _button.alpha = 0;
    UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        _button.alpha = 1;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always increment the alpha. start at 0.0f and end at 1.0f. It will give the fading in effect, and will start out invisible.

```
              yourButton.alpha = 0.0f;
             [yourView addSubview:yourButton];

             [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                  delay:0.0
                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
             animations:^{yourButton.alpha = 1.0;}
             completion:nil];
```

Comment: I used parts of all the answers.  Thank you all for your generous help.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSTimer following method in viewDidApper method

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO];

// write targetMethod: this method get called after every 1 sec. write code to add button as subview to screen in that method or if you can control visibility of buttons then make button visible in targetMethod. when all buttons loaded completely use NSTimer's invalidate method to stop targetMethod from calling.